# Display dynamic menu depending on the dynamic roles in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I am building a CMS. Here I need to generate dynamic menus from the database. Different role user will have different menu access. So there is 
link table created with the user id and the menu they can access.

The other tables are role_tbl, user_info_tbl, menu_info_tbl, user_menu_info_tbl.

So the tables are :

role_tbl :

```
ID | role_name
..............
1 | Admin
2 | Support
```

user_info_tbl :

```
ID | Firt_Name | Last_Name | Role_ID | ....
.....................................
1 |  Max       | Green     | 1
2 |  Hasley    | Laura     | 2
```

menu_info_tbl :

```
ID | Menu_Name | 
.....................................
1 |  News      | 
2 |  Science   |
```

user_menu_info_tbl :

```
ID | User_ID | Menu_ID |....
.....................................
1 |  1       | 1       | 
2 |  1       | 2       | 
3 |  2       | 2       |
```

How can I display the specific users menu as mentioned in the above table depending on ROLEs in Symfony2?

I don't want to hard code the ROLE name in the security.yml as below:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_EVENT_CREATE, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

Thanks for your help and advice.

Comment: Do you use any Bundles like FOSUserBundle or KnpMenuBundle?

Comment: If you are using the default Symfony User-Role system, the relation between user and role should be many to many. In that case, you can dynamically render the menu using something like  ``{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %} Menu 1 {% endif %}``.

Comment: Also, the inbuilt security system mandates that the role names should be prefixed with ``ROLE_`` .